# How to run correctly job in kubernetes from kubernetes app

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am running app in k8s.

Lets say is some web app with admin administration.

In this admin addministration is magic button to run some task.

This task should be started as k8s job.

My question is:

How to start correctly k8s job from this administration backend app.

Should I install `kubectl` into administration app docker image, and just run some `kubectl apply` from my backend app?

Like:

```
// when server receive http
onStart(req, resp) => {
  const { spawn } = require('child_process');
  const ls = spawn('kubectl', ['apply', '-f', 'path-to-job-config.yaml']);
}
```

- in my case I am using nodejs, but I think its verry bad share some k8s configs/credentials in app docker images.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd recommend using a job queue like RabbitMQ here, with a long-running worker process in a deployment.  It will be easier to develop and test and will not be specifically tied to Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [nodejs client library](https://github.com/Goyoo/node-k8s-client) to create a Job by calling kubernetes REST API.

Or you could use an http client library to call the same REST API.

For authentication use a service account token which is a JWT bearer token and can be sent as part of `Authorization` header. The service account needs to be [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) authorization permission to create a Job.